# Delphi SQL.Add() throws incompatability error with custom function which returns a string

Tags: sql, delphi

I have the following code which is constructs an SQL statement based on a number of variables:

```
SQL.Add('SELECT CDbl(Answer) as An FROM v_Outcomes_FirstLastOneYear ' +
  'WHERE ' + GetTool(ReportGrid.Cells[col, 0]) + ' ' +
  'AND (Collector = ' + QuotedStr('Patient') + ') ' +
  'AND (Question=' + GetQuestion(ReportGrid.Cells[col, 0]) + ') ' +
  'AND (Answer is not null) ' +
  'AND (Answer <> ''null '') ');

if Copy(ReportGrid.Cells[col, 0], Length(ReportGrid.Cells[col, 0]), 1) = '1' then
  SQL.Add('AND ('+GetTPoint(first)+') ')
else
  SQL.Add('AND ('+GetTPoint(second)+') ');

SQL.Add('ORDER BY CDbl(Answer)');
```

The top row of `ReportGrid` (a `TStringGrid`) has already been populated with a series of strings such as `'Peds phys 1'`, or `'Peds phys 2'`. The last number is either 1 or 2.

The variables 'first' and 'second' a strings defined further up.

`col` is an integer - this statement is constructed as part of a `for` loop which goes through each of the columns and populates each row with data corresponding to the header.

`GetTool()`, `GetQuestion()` and `GetTPoint()` are functions I have defined. The code for `GetTPoint()` is as follows:

```
function GetTPoint(timepoint: string): string;
begin
  if (timepoint = '0') or (timepoint = 'discharge') then
  begin
    if timepoint = '0' then
      Result := 'FirstAxData=''TRUE'' and DischargeData=''FALSE''';
    if timepoint = 'discharge' then
      Result := 'DischargeData=''TRUE'' and FirstAxData=''FALSE''';
  end
  else
  begin
    timepoint := FormatFloat('0', StrToInt(timepoint)*30.4368);
    Result := '[Date] BETWEEN ([Date of First CPC]+' + timepoint +
      ')-61 AND ([Date of First CPC]+'+timepoint+')+61';
  end;
end;
```

Each of the custom functions are similar and simply returns a string. `GetTool()` and `GetQuestion()` both work fine but `GetTPoint()` throws the following compiler error:

> E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or
>   untyped parameter'

Does anyone know why this is being thrown?

Comment: Assuming the `Question` column is of string type, I guess you just forgot to enclose the value returned by `GetQuestion` into quotes. Use parameters instead. And the reason that it's thrown by the `Add` method call is that in some cases the query might be prepared as you're changing the `SQL` string list (hard to say if that's your case), but it's safer to lock it by `BeginUpdate`, `EndUpdate` block, or assign the query at once to the `Text` property.

Comment: Is that a run time error or a compiler error? which type is `first` that you pass to `GetTPoint`?

Comment: @kobik, ah, there's an error message in this question. I missed that. It's definitely a compiler message.

Comment: @TLama, OP uses the word "throws" which is confusing.

Comment: The error message means that you are passing a reference to a method when the compiler is expecting a string. There's nothing in the code shown that would cause that. Most probably the compiler is passing the method/function instead of evaluating it. In your code are you indirectly referencing the method to be used (e.g. by passing it as a parameter or from a variable)? Also what Delphi version? BTW this has nothing to do with SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you've shown appears inside a `with` statement for the query object you're operating on. Something like this:

```
with SomeQuery do begin
  SQL.Add(...);
  ...
end;
```

You're able to refer to the `SQL` property alone like that because the `with` statement brings the query object's members into the current scope. That means *all* its members, **including the [`First`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.First) method** (used for selecting the first query result). Anything introduced in the scope of the `with` statement will *hide* things of the same name introduced in earlier scopes. That includes the `first` variable you say was declared elsewhere.

When you have the expression `GetTPoint(first)`, the compiler interprets the name `first` as referring to the query method, not the variable. The method is not a string, and calling it doesn't return a string, so the compiler rightfully complains.

The best solution is to stop using `with`. It just introduces brittleness to code. If you simply *must* continue using `with`, then rename your `first` variable so it doesn't interfere with names brought into scope later. There is no way to refer to local variables that have been hidden by another scope. (If `first` were global, you could qualify it with the name of the unit, but global variables should be avoided almost as much as `with` statements.)

Comment: I would so love to upvote this answer multiple times.